# Mysterious issue in my php script

Tags: php

I've been developing a news letter system locally and everything works fine . The mystery begun when I uploaded the whole content to my server , I could see the index page but when I enter the username / Password to log in (in the index page), I get redirected to "authenticate.php " where the Post data are processed this way :

```
<?php include("includes/initialize.php");
if(!isset($_POST['username']) OR !isset($_POST['password']))
{
  // no data were given 
  redirect_to("error.php");
}
elseif(!$user = User::authenticate($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']))
{
  // user not found in the database
  redirect_to("error.php");
}

else {
  $session->login($user);
  redirect_to("enewsletter.php");
}
?>
```

On this page I get stuck (not on localhost ) , the server is rendering a blank page . after some tests , I tell you what happens : If I fall in the if situation i get redirected to `error.php` , but when I enter some credentials , It's doing nothing :/

So I added an echo statement  to keep trace of the code :

and I had this remark, every time the script meets to a line containing a method that looks in the database (OOP approach) the server is always rendering blank pages , I tried it on many pages and it's always the same . I changed the database connection type from `PDO` to `mysqli` (because I thought the server is not supporting `PDO`) but no change !!

Does any one has a clue , what could be the reason?

Comment: Add error reporting on the top of your page;  `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if any php-errors are generated.

Comment: Did you check your database configuration? Is it the same as on localhost or updated to match the one on the server?

Comment: Add error reporting, check if you have no type (usually it's CamelCase issue as linux server is case-sensitive while windows are case-insensitive)

Comment: first append a error_reporting(E_ALL); on top you can see errors, second try yo make all requires relative to the root of your project

Comment: Is there a type in `enewsletter.php` or it's fine?

Comment: That's pretty convoluted logic. are you **SURE** `$user` is getting set when you get to the final `else` clause?

Comment: Ok Thanks to Sander and Error_reporting , I found that it was due  to writing Self instead of self ... It really took me more than 6 Hours ... Thanks Guys for your help

Comment: Please, answer your own question if you know the answer and accept it when stack overflow allows you (2 days from now) to close the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well ,

it was just a " Self instead of self  "  problem ...

Thank you all for your help ;)